# how make seperate file for bottom nav bar in flutter and the use import it render

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, navigation

i just want to make a file which contain nav bar code and it can be drawn over other pages,like the pages are some what scroll able its also having some size issue with the row and column maybe after as shown below the results is cool, and what changes is to make with main.dart file because its will render the most of and root of all

```
//import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:myapp/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter_neumorphic/flutter_neumorphic.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
//import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
//import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

import 'home.dart';

class Nav extends StatefulWidget {
  const Nav({super.key});

  @override
  State<Nav> createState() => _NavState();
}

class _NavState extends State<Nav> {
  Color backgroundColor = const Color(0xffe9edf1);
  Color secondaryColor = const Color(0xffe1e6ec);
  Color accentColor = const Color(0xff2d5765);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: backgroundColor,
      systemNavigationBarColor: secondaryColor,
    ));
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          onTap: (index) {
            //todo implement transition to other screens
            // print(index);
            if (index == 0) {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const Home(),
                ),
              );
            }
            if (index == 1) {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const Home(),
                ),
              );
            }
            if (index == 2) {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const Home(),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
          index: 1,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          color: secondaryColor,
          buttonBackgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          animationDuration: const Duration(
            milliseconds: 300,
          ),
          items: [
            NeumorphicIcon(
              Icons.menu_book_rounded,
              style: NeumorphicStyle(
                color: accentColor,
                intensity: 20,
              ),
            ),
            NeumorphicIcon(
              Icons.home_rounded,
              style: NeumorphicStyle(
                color: accentColor,
                intensity: 20,
              ),
            ),
            NeumorphicIcon(
              Icons.info_rounded,
              style: NeumorphicStyle(
                color: accentColor,
                intensity: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```